# All my sortable jQuery functions stopped working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Okay, this is strange. Suddenly ALL my jQuery scripts have been disabled on my website.

I've checked the links to the jquery scripts and they're still alive.
Goth both links included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This is one of the many jQuery scripts suddenly not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(function() {
            $("#sortable").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings';
                $.post("?id=", order, function(theResponse){
                    $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
                });
            }
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

They worked earlier without problems. My site is http://www.silverart.me, but you can't see any of the scripts when you're not logged in, that's why I included the above example of one of my jQuery scripts.
When I log in, I got control of all elements on my site with different jquery scripts and i can't understand why it doesn't work when it did earlier.

I've tried adding to test if jquery was loading: $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
And jquery does load as intented. But the sortable functions doesn't.

Comment: Can you dump your console log in case you have errors ?

Comment: Wololo: Where do I get console log from Chrome? - Undefined: Can you express yourself a little more?

Comment: @undefined it still works regardless. You get the console by pressing F12 and press console.

Comment: I do indeed have #sortable in my page. Everything was working earlier.

Comment: Alright. Open your console, refresh the page, and copypasta what's written there.

Comment: I get: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #admin_&what=menu&do=add

Comment: That's it. When you have an error on javascript, it will stop interpreting the following lines. Fix that error you are currently having (the console gives you the line number), and your function will most probably work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for letting me know about the console! I just went back to the programming world. Highly appreciated!

Comment: Don't mention it! You can also run jQuery or javascript on the fly in the console! Good for debugging and doing `console.log("lollolo")` instead of those goddamn alert boxes.

Comment: Your answers are hillarious! Can't you make an answer I can accept? I'm new to this site.

Comment: Alright buddy, I gave you an official answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the answer for this trivial question remains to be unknown. Your pasted code looks and feels valid, and as discussed in the comments, the browser interprets JavaScript line by line until it encounters an uncaught error. Once you have successfully fixed that error the browser should be able to run your sortable function.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem.
I had the console open and when I closed it sortable came back to life.